# How to make Leaflet map reads street from input value?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

There is an option for leaflet map to add search box, but on map, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/adding-a-search-box-to-a-leaflet-js-example.

I need that option from some input field, not from search box placed on map.
Is there any possibility that leaflet map reads value from input value of user and not search box on map?